# How to add a color indicator (LED-lookalike) to a JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I want to add a color-indicator to my JFrame. It should be turned to be red when I click a button and if I do not click a button it should be green. How should I implement this?

Comment: in JFrame's content, you can add a JLabel, do you want to add at the top of the JFrame, at decoration ? - near the minimize and maximize buttons?

Comment: do you want it in the header? What do you want as an indicator? be more specific

Comment: I want it to be in any place in the jframe and very small it can be circular.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
JLabel lblLed = new JLabel("•");
lblLed.setForeground(Color.Green);
```

Add an ChangeListener to your JButton and in the StateChanged() method add this:

```
if (buttonIsPressed) {
    lblLed.setForeground(Color.Red);
} else {
    lblLed.setForeground(Color.Green);
}
```

Comment: +1 for unicode; see also [`ColorIcon`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3072979/230513).